# selenium chromedriver is throwing a version error but version is matched

Tags: c#, selenium

Can someone explain why I am getting this error?  Doesn't make any sense.  I am using version 80.0 yet it is throwing version error for 80.0...
[image: chrome driver exeption]

Test Name:  SmokeTestGoatsbeard
Test FullName:  Patch1UITests.Program.SmokeTestGoatsbeard
Test Source:    S:\SourceCode\patchtests\Patch1UITests\Program.cs : line 33
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:03.877

Result StackTrace:
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor()
   at Patch1UITests.Program.Initialize() in S:\SourceCode\patchtests\Patch1UITests\Program.cs:line 27
--TearDown
   at Patch1UITests.Program.CleanUp() in S:\SourceCode\patchtests\Patch1UITests\Program.cs:line 66
Result Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
  (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (SessionNotCreated)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: could you please share the entire log :0

Comment: added comment..

Comment: One more thing just for the cross verification my friend. Could you please share the chrome browser version

Comment: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I didn't think this mattered, but it makes sense, although i just updated the driver to 83, and then i still got the original error referencing 80.0?  caching issue?

Comment: Maybe I am not much aware of c#  but in the attached screenshot I can see that you have added Selenium.Chrome.Version as 80.0.0

Comment: visual studio was just being visual studio, deleted the chromedriver.exe, reinstalled package for 83.0, clean & build, works fine now! :shrugs